# I need to cut particular text from file to display only particular column using BASH script

Tags: bash

I have a bash script that call another bash script and stores output of that in a text file. Now I would like to delete column from that file. For example following file, I need to display only COUNT, CKA CLASS AND CKA LABEL column and delete rest of the section. If I cut the column using awk or sed it will start cutting from PKCS11 provider line

```
PKCS11 provider found specified slot label: admin (slot: 76147, index: 14)
+-------+-----------------+------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+-------------+-------------+------------+
| COUNT |    CKA CLASS    |                            CKA LABEL                             |                              CKA ID                              | CKA KEY TYPE | CKA KEY LEN | CKA SUBJECT | CKA ISSUER |
+-------+-----------------+------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+-------------+-------------+------------+
|   001 | PRIVATE_KEY     | d4a12e598081d863ff371904d42ba6b0d1b19b1f4990477d60sdadafdfdfdffd | c3a12e508081d868c3633c79aa3ff371904d42ba6b0d1b19b1f4040477d6070a | CKK_ECDSA    |           0 |             |            |
|   002 | PUBLIC_KEY      | e5a12g7025l1d868c36331904d42baa6b0d1b19b1ggf4990477dsfdsdfs6070a | d4a12e59891cd868c3633c79aa3ff371904d42b77d6070asfewerww345a122rs | CKK_ECDSA    |           0 |             |            |
+-------+-----------------+------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+-------------+-------------+------------+
```

I would like to get the output like this:

```
PKCS11 provider found specified slot label: admin (slot: 76147, index: 14)
| COUNT |  CKA CLASS  |                            CKA LABEL                             |     
+-------+-----------------+------------------------------------------------------------------+
|   001 | PRIVATE_KEY | ed53bc0ef5cbe3aa0d8994d27dsfdsdfsdfdsf9273f2810defc159e310743d92 |
|   002 | PUBLIC_KEY  | ed53bc0ef5cbe3aa0d8994d27b922ce03dsdfsdd73f2810defc159e310743d92 |
```

Comment: I think I know what you want but it will be easier for everyone if you express precisely what you want the output to look like give this input. That is, add it to your post. Even if you have to hand edit it, it will go a long way to everyone's understanding.

Comment: Is `perl` allowed?

Comment: No .. I am just using BASH

Comment: Are you sure you can't get the output in any other format? Wouldn't it be easier to just pass formatting to the `pkc11*` tool you are using? Do you care about the `+------+-----+` parts? Can you just filter first three columns or do you need to check which column has which label? If you can, just `cut -d'|' -f-4`

Comment: Maybe I should have asked: what you do you mean when you say BASH? Because when I read that, I immediately think you are not allowed to use any external commands, like `ls`, `cut`, `sed`, `awk`, `more`, `head`, `tail`, and so forth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to approach it is to get rid of the lines you don't want with `sed` and then just print out the first `94` characters of the lines that remain, e.g.

```
$ while read line; do echo "${line:0:94}"; done < <(sed '2d;$d' file)
PKCS11 provider found specified slot label: admin (slot: 76147, index: 14)
| COUNT |    CKA CLASS    |                            CKA LABEL                             |
+-------+-----------------+------------------------------------------------------------------+
|   001 | PRIVATE_KEY     | d4a12e598081d863ff371904d42ba6b0d1b19b1f4990477d60sdadafdfdfdffd |
|   002 | PUBLIC_KEY      | e5a12g7025l1d868c36331904d42baa6b0d1b19b1ggf4990477dsfdsdfs6070a |
```

(**note:** if you are not using bash where *process substitution* is available to feed the `while` loop, you can just call the `sed` expression first and pipe the result to the while loop.)

---

**Edit Based on Comment**

If the width of the first 3 fields of the format isn't known before hand, you can add a *command substitution* to determine the total width, for example:

```
$ width=$(awk -F'|' '{print length($2)+length($3)+length($4)+4}' < <(sed -n 3p file))
  while read line; do
      echo "${line:0:$width}"
  done < <(sed '2d;$d' file)
PKCS11 provider found specified slot label: admin (slot: 76147, index: 14)
| COUNT |    CKA CLASS    |                            CKA LABEL                             |
+-------+-----------------+------------------------------------------------------------------+
|   001 | PRIVATE_KEY     | d4a12e598081d863ff371904d42ba6b0d1b19b1f4990477d60sdadafdfdfdffd |
|   002 | PUBLIC_KEY      | e5a12g7025l1d868c36331904d42baa6b0d1b19b1ggf4990477dsfdsdfs6070a |
```

Another slightly shorter way that eliminates the `while` loop and uses `cut` to trim to the combined width of the first 3 fields with delimiters could be:

```
$ width=$(awk -F'|' '{print length($2)+length($3)+length($4)+4}' < <(sed -n 3p file))
sed '2d;$d' file | cut -c -$width
PKCS11 provider found specified slot label: admin (slot: 76147, index: 14)
| COUNT |    CKA CLASS    |                            CKA LABEL                             |
+-------+-----------------+------------------------------------------------------------------+
|   001 | PRIVATE_KEY     | d4a12e598081d863ff371904d42ba6b0d1b19b1f4990477d60sdadafdfdfdffd |
|   002 | PUBLIC_KEY      | e5a12g7025l1d868c36331904d42baa6b0d1b19b1ggf4990477dsfdsdfs6070a |
```

Comment: Unless the field width varies.

Comment: Yes, no doubt, but the wonky SQL type output pretty much forces a fixed width for a simple solution. You can always uses a more involved regex (or simple iteration) to pick out the widths if needed.

Comment: @JeffHolt if you want to predetermine the width based on the content, you can take the 3rd line for example and do `awk -F'|' '{print length($2)+length($3)+length($4)+4}' < <(sed -n 3p file)`

Answer (score 1):

You could use `cut` twice:

```sh
cut -d"|" -f-4 inputfile | cut -d"+" -f-4
```

output:

```
PKCS11 provider found specified slot label: admin (slot: 76147, index: 14)
+-------+-----------------+------------------------------------------------------------------
| COUNT |    CKA CLASS    |                            CKA LABEL                             
+-------+-----------------+------------------------------------------------------------------
|   001 | PRIVATE_KEY | d4a12e598081d863ff371904d42ba6b0d1b19b1f4990477d60sdad 
|   002 | PUBLIC_KEY  | e5a12g7025l1d868c36331904d42ba6b0d1b19b1f4990477d6070a 
+-------+-----------------+------------------------------------------------------------------
```